# nodejs) How add platform info in package,json or package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js

I need to install package 'sharp' with command

```
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

because I use Windows.

but, because package.json and package-lock.json don't have command info (--arch=x64 --platform=linux), If i run 'npm install' on other computer, then npm runs just 'npm install sharp'.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can't you just npm install sharp? `npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp` only if you are using for lambda

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I'm using aws lambda and serverless framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installation of sharp for lambda. You need to install sharp first, then remove node modules. This is a manual step, cannot be included in your package.json

> npm install sharp
>
> rmdir /s /q node_modules/sharp
>
> npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp

You can create a bash script in your source root

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install sharp 
rmdir /s /q node_modules/sharp 
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

then `chmod +x script.sh`

You can then create a README.md in your root folder and let other users know they need to run this script in order to install sharp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is It impossible to make just 'npm install' work like 'npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp' ?

Comment: It's not possible, but there's another way to install it during deployment. - https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2230#issuecomment-698653336

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug when I deployed my app (using Sharp) from Windows to AWS with serverless.

I actually installed sharp for **Linux** on my **Windows** machine. Then I used serverless deploy, and somehow the Linux version would run on AWS Lambda.

My guess is that the package was included in the zip package sent to aws.